# JMS - How does message API setJMSredelivered and getJMSredelivered work?

Tags: java, jms

I am trying to understand these two API's : `setJMSRedelivered` and `getJMSRedelivered` for my project.
Link : http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/jms/Message.html#getJMSRedelivered()

Steps used :

1. Call `setJMSRedelivered(true)` on message we want to publish on a topic.
2. publish the message.
3. Consume the message. Call `getJMSRedelivered()` on message.

It should receive true. But its retuning false.
Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you are no supposed to set the `JMSRedelivered` property while publishing a message. This property will be set by the messaging provider when it delivers a message more than once.

According to JMS specification

*If a client receives a message with the JMSRedelivered indicator set, it is likely, but not guaranteed, that this message was delivered but not acknowledged in the past. In general, a provider must set the JMSRedelivered message header field of a message whenever it is redelivering a message. If the field is set to true, it is an indication to the consuming application that the message may have been delivered in the past and that the application should take extra precautions to prevent duplicate processing.*

*This header field has no meaning on send and is left unassigned by the
sending method.*

Read carefully the last line, it says `JMSRedelivered` has `no` meaning when a message is sent.

In your case, since the message has **not** been redelivered, the `getJMSRedelivered` property call is returning `FALSE`.

**Update**

Sample code to test `JMSRedelivered` property.

```
 // Create JMS objects
 connection = cf.createConnection();
 System.out.println("Created connection to " + queueManager);
 // Create a transacted session.
 session = connection.createSession(true, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
 System.out.println("Session created");

 Destination topicScore = session.createTopic("/SCORE");
 MessageConsumer consScore = session.createConsumer(topicScore );

 JMSBytesMessage msg=null;
 // Receive message first
 msg = (JMSBytesMessage) colesConsumer.receiveNoWait();
 System.out.println(msg.getJMSRedelivered);

 // Rollback the previous receive, to force messaging provider to redeliver the message
 session.rollback();

 // receive message again
 msg = (JMSBytesMessage) colesConsumer.receiveNoWait();
 // This time JMSRedelivered will be true.
 System.out.println(msg.getJMSRedelivered);
```

Hope this helps to you.

Comment: So if i redeliver the same message again and after consuming with this flag set to true..... it should work?

Comment: It's the messaging provider that needs to redeliver the message, not your sender application.  See code snippet in my update above.

Answer (score 0):

setJMSredelivered is managed by the container, if you set it to true and publish the message [which has not been 'redelivered'] the container sets setJMSredelivered to false.

When the message is delivered, and, for example, something fatal happens, the container will rollback the call and sets setJMSredelivered to true.